# Present continuous or simple present? and is "it's decided" English?

Tags: present-tense

I hesitate a lot between four alternatives. Could you help me by telling me which one is the more correct please?

> 1. I've made my mind up, I leave you.
> 2. I've made my mind up, I'm leaving you.
> 3. It's decided, I leave you.
> 4. It's decided, I'm leaving you.

The idea is to say to someone (orally, so no need to be formal) that I've made a decision which I'm *very* sure of.

I have the impression that the expression "It's decided" isn't used a lot, is it?

Comment: Looks like you haven't decided!

Comment: Nota bene: written English uses words, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose *I've made my mind up, I'm leaving you.*  The first clause is in the active voice, which is almost always the best choice.  (Surely, you are not leaving me because some group or the other told you you must.)  The continuous present makes it clear that you do not plan come back any time soon.  In the interest of completeness, all four examples are comma splices.  *I've made my mind up; I'm leaving you.*  OR *I've made my mind up. I'm leaving you.*